# NumberFormatException #1 Kotlin Replace String value

Tags: string, kotlin, str-replace, numberformatexception, parseint

Error code

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "44,379.3933"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
```

This is written in Kotlin. How can I remove "," "." and "3933" from the input string?

```
val usdRate:String = (JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("bpi").getJSONObject("USD")["rate"]  as String)
val text = usdRate.replace("\"", ".");
val satosh = text.toInt() / 100000000
```

Comment: Your question hasn't been formatted properly. Though, as far as I understand, you could do this before converting to Int: `usdRate.replace(",", "")`.

Comment: @NishantJalan, add your comment as an answer so that  @ Saylavie1997 can then accept is as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usdRate.replace(",", "")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).